Large gaps in brick wall
In my basement, found some large gaps in the wall between bricks.
How do I go about fixing that


Repointing
Scrape out any loose mortar, possibly chisel off the messy globs from the surface, mix up new mortar, push it in, tool the surface so it looks nicer.
You should probably spray the bricks with water before you start putting new mortar in place, so they don't suck all the water out of it before it can cure. And then spray it down for a few days after the inital set to aid the cure. Cementitious products need moisture to cure and harden properly, they should not be allowed to dry out too soon.
Parging
You can also trowel a layer of mortar over the whole surface of the wall to make it smooth and hide the sloppy brickwork. Do that after repointing to addess the voids and any loose mortar.
